# Create dynamic table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

i have a problem with mySQL.
I have a table like this:

```
Time                    Sensor    Value   
2012-10-16 14:42:32 VI0    0      
2012-10-16 14:42:32 VI1    0      
2012-10-16 14:42:32 VI2    0      
2012-10-16 14:42:32 VI3    0      
2012-10-16 14:42:33 VI0    1      
2012-10-16 14:42:33 VI1    1      
2012-10-16 14:42:33 VI2    1      
2012-10-16 14:42:33 VI3    1
```

i have a table "`sensor`" with all the name sensor and other information.
Is it possible rearrange that table in a table like this:

```
Time                    VI0        VI1      VI2    VI3

2012-10-16 14:42:32 0      0         0      0

2012-10-16 14:42:32 1      1         1      1
```

I'm looking the pivot table but i don't know if it is the right way.

P.S. maybe i found the solution:

SELECT time,GROUP_CONCAT(value) as Sensor FROM measure2 GROUP BY time;

time                    GROUP_CONCAT(value)

2012-10-16 14:42:32 0,0,0,0

Instead of GROUP_CONCAT can i write the name of sensor with comma?

Comment: Have a look at these links: [Dynamic pivot tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html), [Automate pivot table queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523).

Comment: Are VI0 etc always zero or one or do the values differ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski have different values, are measure's plant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you need to use a prepared statement to `pivot` the data dynamically.  This will use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when Sensor = ''',
      Sensor,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      Sensor
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  measure2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT time, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM measure2 
                  GROUP BY time');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2ef/1)

If you have known values, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select time,
  max(case when sensor = 'VI0' then value end) as VI0,
  max(case when sensor = 'VI1' then value end) as VI1,
  max(case when sensor = 'VI2' then value end) as VI2,
  max(case when sensor = 'VI3' then value end) as VI3
from measure2
group by time
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6529/1)